# Impacted of a conjugated filter

Tags: filters, convolution, finite-impulse-response, least-squares

What is the effect of using a conjugated FIR filter? I have a use case where a weight vector, x, can be estimated using the least squares approximation:

$$Ax=b$$ $$ A^HAx = A^Hb$$ $$ x = (A^HA)^{-1}  A^Hb$$

If the conjugation is reversed then the output weight vector would be calculated as such:  $$ x = (A^TA^*)^{-1}  A^Tb^* $$

I acknowledge that this is an incorrect derivation of least squares. However, I am working on a software implementation and realized the conjugation could happen in the incorrect way and that results in a conjugated x vector solution.

This result x vector can be thought of as an FIR filter for this particular application, which is convolved with the complex baseband input data. The output data after convolution is unchanged whether I conjugate the weight vector x or not. What is the impact/side effect of having a conjugated weight vector?

Comment: Are any of your A, x or b complex or are they real ?

Comment: Assuming `H` is the "conjugate transpose" operator, your last equation can't be right. $Ab^H$ doesn't work since since the inner matrix dimensions don't match. $b^H$ has dimensions of $1xN$

Comment: Yes, all are complex valued. Assume simple transpose on A for rhs, I agree the matrix dimensions are mismatched on the second (incorrect) equation

Comment: And yes H is conjugate transpose

Comment: Sorry , you need clean up your equations first. We can't tell you what the difference between the two equation is if one of them doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @Hilmar - I updated to reflect the conjugate on b. I will say, that's the main difference here..which vector/matrix is conjugated.

Comment: Assume $A$ has a dimension of $M\times N$, $A^HA$ is $N\times N$ but $AA^H$ is $M\times M$, whose inverse has the same dimension and can't be right multiplied by $A^T$! Did you mean the minimum norm solution which is $x = (AA^H)^{-1} A b$?

Comment: Good catch. Fixed it.

Comment: @ZRHan - any thoughts on this?